# ERROR: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to test execution of a transaction with table column constrain for duplicated value:

first run:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

  INSERT INTO table()...;

COMMIT;

result:
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "uk_22de7s2pr0nc0c713fd38lgei"
DETAIL:  Key (bin)=(111103) already exists.
SQL state: 23505
```

second run:

```
ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
SQL state: 25P02
```

And I get always the same error in pgadmin.

Do you know how I can properly rollback or catch the exception from the first time?

Comment: Use [ROLLBACK](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-rollback.html) and/or  [SAVEPOINT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-savepoint.html).

Answer (score 1):

What do you want to do in the event of a duplicate key value:  ignore the conflict, update the existing row, or report the exception. To ignore the error, use `ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING` with the `INSERT`. Similarly, to update the existing row, use `ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE ...`. If you want to report the exception after terminating the transaction, then wrap the code in a plpgsql block:

```
DO
LANGUAGE plpgsql
$BLOCK$
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO ...
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    ROLLBACK;
    RAISE;
END
$BLOCK$;
```

Note: For a single statement it's not necessary to use `START TRANSACTION` and `COMMIT`. When not in a plpgsql block, procedure, or function, each statement is implicitly a single transaction. By not using `START TRANSACTION`, the exception will still be reported, but the transaction will be automatically terminated.

Comment: I get error when I use the code `ERROR: SSL SYSCALL error: EOF detected`

Comment: Plese provide the setup and full code that is producing the error. Without those, it's impossible to diagnose the source of the exception. The specific PostgreSQL version might also be needed.